# Making an asynchronous call synchronous in tornado

Tags: python, design-patterns, tornado, coroutine

I have the following problem.

I work on a tornado based application server. Most of the code can be synchronous and the web interface does not really use any of the asynchronous facilities of Tornado.

I now have to interface to an (asynchronous) legacy backend for which I use the `tornado.iostream` interface to send commands. Responses to these commands are sent asynchronously, together with other periodic information, such as status updates.

The code is wrapped in a common interface that is also used for other backends.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
# this is executed on initialization
self.stream.read_until_close(self.close, self.read_from_backend)

# this is called whenever data arrives on the input stream
def read_from_backend(self, data):
     if data in pending:
         # it means we got a response to a request we sent out
         del self.pending[data]
     else:
         # do something else

# this sends a request to the backend
def send_to_backend(self, data):
     self.pending[data] = True
     while data in self.pending:
          # of course this does not work
          time.sleep(1)
     return
```

Of course this does not work, as `time.sleep(1)` will not allow `read_from_backend()` to run any further.

How do I solve this? I want the `send_to_backend()` to return only when the response is received. Is there a way I can yield control to `read_from_backend` without yet returning from the method?

Please note that it is difficult to do this at a in the web layer using @asynchronous and @gen.engine, because that would require a full rewrite of all requests in our web layer. Is there a way I can implement the same design pattern somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good idea may be to look into using gevent. By MonkeyPatching and using a simple decorator I wrote you can get very easily nice asynchronous views which are written in a synchronous manner (blocking style).

You can reuse most of the code from a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292407/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-the-combination-of-gevent-and-tornado/13299083#13299083).

Though you may not want to use gevent for different reasons (not having it has a dependency):

Admitting that you've monkey patched your global process with :

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

The above patches threads, sockets, sleep ... so they go through gevent's hub (the hub is to gevent what the ioloop is to tornado).

Once patched and by using the @gasync decorator in my previous answer your view could simply be :

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @gasync
     def get(self):
         # Parse the input data in some fashion
         data = get_data_from_request()

         # This could be anything using python sockets, urllib ...
         backend_response = send_data_to_backend(data)

         # Write data to HTTP client
         self.write(backend_response)

         # You have to finish the response yourself since it's asynchronous
         self.finish()
```

I find that gevent's simplicity and "elegance" far outweighs any advantage you would have writing async code with tornado's ioloop.

In my case I had to use legacy code written in a synchronous fashion, so basically gevent was a life safer, all I had to do was monkey patch and write that decorator and I could use all that legacy code without any modifications.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not clear what the relation is to my original question. I must admit I know nothing of gevent.

Comment: Gevent is a coroutine based networking library for Python. If you don't know it, you should most certainly check it out (http://www.gevent.org/).

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use gevent for asynchronous networking instead of tornado's iostreams. Since gevent uses cooperative coroutines, once you've monkey patched python's sockets you'll be able to write asynchronous networking code in a regular synchronous style.

The main advantage is that it lowers the complexity of writing asynchronous networking code and it's pretty much straight forward to use (all you need to do is monkey patch).

Comment: I just looked at the documentation. This looks very much like what I want. Will try if I can hook it up to tornado after the weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately, `gevent` will not compile on my legacy system. It is an OpenSUSE system, somewhere around the 10.0 range and I run into problems with libevent. I will not pursue this any further, but I will accept the answer.